# What is the purpose of a coffee press?

Tags: equipment

At one of my local cafes, you can order your drink in a coffee press. It looks like a large mug with a pump on top:

[image]

What is this used for? Does it affect the taste or strength of the coffee?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a [French press](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_press).

Put ground coffee inside it, pour hot water, stir a little bit, and then wait for 2 to 4 minutes (or longer if you want a strong and bitter coffee).

After waiting, use the pump to filter the ground from the coffee and pour the coffee into your mug.

I recommend using coarse or medium ground coffee, otherwise, the coffee will go through the filter and will end up in your cup (and mouth).

Some extra information [here](https://www.craftcoffee.com/how-to-make-coffee/french-press-brew-guide).

Comment: If you let the coffee sit in the press and then pour it out to drink - as it holds more than a single cup worth; how does that affect the taste of coffee?

Comment: If it sits too long in the press, it will turn bitter, and also contain more caffeine.

Answer (score 2):

It is french press coffee. The advantage of it over other brewing methods is it allows more the oils and oil based flavors in the coffee to remain. Drip coffee uses filters that strain out the oil. This is personal preference. If you are trying to avoid fat or if you don't like the flavors a particular coffee's oils impart to the drink you may not like french press coffee, but you could also be one of the people who loves the taste of french press. It can even vary based on the beans. With a french press the coffee should sit for about 4 minutes and then be poured out. If it sits too long it gets very bitter.